# NSPredicateEditor query not working

Tags: objective-c, nspredicateeditor

I've got a Problem with my NSPredicateEditor. I want to use it for filtering a array of dictionarys.

NSArray events = {(Stadt=>Berlin), (Stadt=>Munich), nil }

The following code is working:

```
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Stadt LIKE %@", @"Berlin"];
    NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
    events = [events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The NSLog result is: Stadt LIKE "Berlin"

If I get the predicate from NSPredicateEditor I get the same NSLog result but the result array (events) is empty !

Code:

```
    predicate = [predicateEditor predicate];
    XLog(@"%@", predicate);
    events = [events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

`NSPredicateEditor` does not have a `-predicate` method.  It has an `objectValue` method, and you should use that instead.  Perhaps you could provide more information, such as what is getting logged in the second block?

Comment: The log in the second block is the same. With objectValue and predicate. Stadt LIKE "Berlin"

Comment: @Andreas well if the predicate being returned is the same, it would seem the problem lies elsewhere...